# Logic for getting (0,3) (3,6) (6,9) based on a variable

Tags: javascript, logic

I have a variable `var position`. Also, `0<= position <=2`

I'm trying to write a logic where:

position is 0, I get `array.slice(0,3)`

position is 1, I get `array.slice(3,6)`

and

position is 2, I get `array.slice(6,9)`

What generic logic can be used for this in a single statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just multiply by 3?

```
array.slice(position * 3, (position + 1) * 3)
```